# undefined method `strftime_format'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stamp

I'm use gems stamp and StampI18n.

Code:

```
@post.time = @date.localize_stamp("1 Jan 1999, 21:45", :locale => 'en')
```

Result:

```
undefined method `strftime_format' for Thu, 09 Jun 2011:Date
```

What's the problem?

Comment: `strftime_format` is probably expecting a DateTime and you're passing it a Date.

Comment: date = Date.new(2011, 6, 9)
  post.time = date.localize_stamp("1 Jan 1999", :locale => 'en')